# How to color words of cells in xlsx

Tags: python-3.x, list, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I have list of  sentance, which i  want to write to xlsx.
I have a second list with words. I want that all words from the second list that are also in the first list are supposed to be red.

My code so far will not color the words. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('strings.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
red = workbook.add_format({'color': 'red'})
sentance = [
    'HI guys i need',
    'some help with',
    'this.',
    'Some stuff i ',
    'allready tried',
    'Thank you',
    'For your help',
]
list_word=['you','help','tried','some more stoff','and more stuff']

worksheet.set_column('A:A', 40)

for row_num, sentance in enumerate(sentance):

    format_pairs = []
    for word in list_word:
        find_word = word
        for word in sentance:

            if word == find_word:
                format_pairs.extend((red, word))


            else:
                format_pairs.append(word)
    worksheet.write_rich_string(row_num, 0, *format_pairs)

workbook.close()
```

**EDIT:**
I saw the other posted, the problem is that i have a list of words not just one, which i want to change the color for. I edited the code a littel.
The list is a variable and the sentance also, so they always change, so it makes no sence for me to write a code for just one or two words.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to change font color in excel using python xlsxwriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50495463/unable-to-change-font-color-in-excel-using-python-xlsxwriter)

Comment: I have never tried xlsx. But I think in your line `worksheet.set_column('A:A', 40)`, it should be something like this `worksheet.set_column('A:1', 40)` or not? i am not sure about this stuff.

Comment: I edit the question, because the other post ask for always the same word to be colored, i have a list of words. I would be still really glad for some help

Answer (score 0):

Please check the help document https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_colors.html

It provides information on how to set colors for cells